# Threading android doubts

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask, loader

I´m working on a portability of a human-machine dialogue open source system JVoiceXML from Java to Android. The system is based on the VoiceXML 2.0 standard which uses XML documents to create the interactions between the human and the machine.

The idea is to provide Android with a means to creat apps that interact with the user via voice using the TTS and SpeechRecognizer android engines.

We´re trying to do so without having any visual effect on the screen, just as a system service would work. For now I´ve tried to implement our system as a service, but I´m having trouble with threading and Android killing my service.

The question is, which approach do you think fits best my proyect, an AsyncTask, a service, a Loader? Maybe a service that starts an AsyncTask or a Loader?

The requirements would be:

1. My VoiceXML Interpreter gets fired up by an app Intent (intent filter is how I´m having it now)
2. It recieves a document from the app. Also the app can stop my Interpreter , or at least stop the interpreting of that document.
3. The Interpreter interacts with the TTS and creates a Speech Recognizer engine.
4. The Interpreter itself is a java thread that has to be started from the service, loader, or asyncTask.
5. Only one app can make use of my Interpreter (no need for parallel connections)

Please let me know if more info is needed to comprehend the problem.

thanks in advance,

Marcos.

Answer (score 1):

If the bulk of your work is already done within another thread, I don't see a need for an AsyncTask. Just use the interpreter from your Service. You'll need a Service no matter what if you want to provide something without a user interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I am using a Service but its getting killed with a ANR because the interpreter takes too long...I am gonna open another question with a more specific question about it. thanks!